# detect end of operator<< sequence

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sequence, terminator

In C++ how do you detect programmatically the end of a sequence of the form:

```
object << argument1 << argument2 << argument3;
```

Let's say I have overloaded operator<< like this

```
Object& operator<<(Object& object, Argument& argument) {
...
}
```

The above expression will be evaluated like this:

```
(((object << argument1) << argument2) << argument3);
```

For the sake of the argument let's say object is a logger. I stream data into the logger. Once the last argument (argument3 in this case, but the number of arguments is not fixed of course) has been streamed into object, I want object to assemble the message and post it. How can I do this without having to write something like this:

```
object << argument1 << argument2 << argument3 << EOM;
```

Thank you. Any input welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers mention, using an "end-of-message" marker is a good design.

But if you really need what you asked for, you can do it like this: You implement the EOM idea like you normally would, and then add this class:

```
class AutoEnd
{
private:
    mutable Object & m_obj;

public:
    explicit AutoEnd (Object & obj) : m_obj (obj) {}
    ~AutoEnd () {m_obj << EOM;}

    Object & obj () const {return m_obj;}
};

template <typename T>
AutoEnd const & operator << (AutoEnd const & ae, T && arg)
{
    ae.obj() << std::forward<T>(arg);
    return ae;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Object object;
...
AutoEnd(object) << argument1 << argument2 << argument3;
```

which will do what you want. Some notes:

- You can obviously still use the explicit `EOM` method after adding `AutoEnd`. This gives you greater flexibility to use whichever method where it makes sense.
- The key in this technique is the destructor for `AutoEnd`, which will be called at the end of the line it was instantiated in.
- You can implement it better than above. Most importantly, it's a good idea to make the constructor of `AutoEnd` to be private or somehow signal the user that they should not create normal instances of `AutoEnd`, because they are useless that way and they keep references to you `Object`s and may try to use them after they are destroyed.
- You can only use this technique safely if `operator <<` for `Object` doesn't throw an exception, because it's called inside a destructor and *destructors should not throw*.
- Since `AutoEnd` is designed to be used as a temporary object, and you can only work with `const &` of temporary objects easily, `operator <<` gets and returns a constant reference, and the stored `Object` reference is declared as `mutable`. In my opinion, this is not a bad design, since `AutoEnd` objects don't have any internal state (apart from the `Object &`) and the correctness of calling `operator <<` on that needs to be assured elsewhere (i.e. `AutoEnd` doesn't need to care about that.)
- You should make `AutoEnd` non-copyable.

Comment: That's certainly an interesting use for a destructor.

Comment: @chris Seems to me like a nice little utility to have in your toolbox! Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: I like this. Added to my Toolbox :)

Comment: Works like a charm for me. The only change I had to make was to make the signature of template function template <typename T>
AutoEnd & operator << (AutoEnd & ae, T && arg) into template <typename T>
const AutoEnd & operator << (const AutoEnd & ae, T && arg)

Comment: @chris.schuette: Why was that? Was there a compile problem? Because logically, the `AutoEnd` arguments are not constants (I think!)

Comment: Yes, there is. I can't just copy it in here because it is too long. I think the problem is that basically AutoEnd(object) creates a temporary and you can only take const. references of that. That creates another problem however, because it means that in the line ae.obj() << std::forward<T>(arg); ae.obj() will return a const reference to object. So I had to declare the thing inside object that the streamed data is recorded in "mutable". That works now and I am happy with it. But maybe I missed something and there is a much more beautiful way to handle this.

Comment: @chris.schuette: No, you're right. That sounds logical. I posted the code without trying it, so... sorry about that! And declaring the object inside as `mutable` is a sensible thing to do here. I will edit my answer to incorporate this. Thanks.

Comment: I disagree that it is good design to use an EOM marker. Too many rare and hard-to-unit-test but important logs have been missed due to forgotten EOM markers. This solution is good design to me.

Comment: The only downside to this I see is that sometimes you may wish to construct a message over multiple statements, and don't want them automatically flushed at the end of each statement, in which case the easy workaround is to build the message into a stringstream first.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (unless `object` gets destroyed after each line). It is quite common to have something like `EOM`.

Answer (score 0):

Just think, why sequence notation is possible. It's happened, because `operator<<` returns reference to stream. You can write:

```
ostream& s = object << argument1;
s << argument2
s << argument3
...
```

And where is real end of sequence? Only you know, because you design and code it. So `EOM` is good common practice - use it.